# Error while running a Android App through Automation Testing

Tags: mobile, automation, xamarin.android, cucumber, calabash-android

When i Build my app it shows test server created, But when i Run a app it shows me the following error which i have mentioned below. For more details i have attached a screenshot please refer it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5PiC.png)

**Scenario: Then I see "Hello World!" # features/my_first.feature:3
  More than one device connected. Specify device serial using ADB_DEVICE_ARG (Ru
ntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:18:in `Before'
  App did not start (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in`Before'
Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:3 # Scenario: Then I see "Hello World!"
1 scenario (1 failed)
0 steps
0m17.546s**

Please help me out with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying that you have more than one android device (real or emulated) connected to the machine.  Calabash uses adb to communicate with the device and adb needs to know which device to talk to if more than one is connected.  Either disconnect the device(s) you don't want to use, or set an environment variable with the serial number of your device to ADB_DEVICE_ARG.

You can find the serial number of your device with the command line

```
adb devices
```

Comment: I had only one device connected to the Calabash, Then also i am getting this type of error, Do i need to change anything in these 2 files ? "./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb" "./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb "

Comment: if you run 'adb devices' in a terminal on the machine what comes back?

Comment: If more than one device shows up you need to set an environment variable for ADB_DEVICE_ARG to be the serial number of the device you want to use